# Drag and drop images like in a puzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

How can i make 2 divs which contain images to drag-drop and fit each other.My code looks like :

Edit: link for project http://www.fileshare.ro/e30355196

```
$(function() {
    $( "#right img" ).draggable
    ({

    revert: "invalid"

    });
    $( "#left" ).droppable({

      tolerance: 'fit',

      drop: function( event, ui ) {
         $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#left"));
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Damn...now i saw,but main problem is in edit..

Comment: Could you improve your question by providing more relevant code and maybe a jsfiddle?!

Comment: @a.Wolff its in edit ...i uploaded whole project coz its abit harder to explain...Right pictures should fit in left pictures :( thats all

Comment: Well, no one will download a complete project just to fix what seems to be just a little unexpected behaviour. At least for sure i won't...

Comment: understood...but there are also images...images like a puzzle to fit .How can i fit these images in 1 image?

Comment: @A.Wolff Not downloading the project, but wanted to have a go anyway. . with your images as Classes you wont need the css part of the below example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find attached fiddle:
Hopefully this will give you a good start.. like wolff said, I aint downloading an entire project writing the whole thing..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/qs3TF/1/

Best of luck with it..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#pieces>div').draggable();
$('#puz>div').droppable({
    accept: "#pieces>div",
    //        activeClass: "ui-state-hover", //can be cool to have these..
    //        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
     drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css('background-color', 'red').css({ //you wont need this as your classes will all stay the same.
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            height:100,
            width: 100
        }).appendTo(this);
        //disable draggable on them also..
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thx for ur time,i'm gonna try it right now.Thank you!